# How to configure syntax token of tags

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sails.js, nunjucks

I am currently using sails.js with ejs templating but wish to switch to nunjucks. I have done this with no problems.

I have found however that the tags of nunjucks are the same as that of angularjs and wish to change them.

I have look at the documentation here: https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#customizing-syntax

I don't know how to do this in a sails.js context.

I have tried adding a 'tags' setting to config / view.js.

I've tried running the configure command in bootstrap.js.

Could anybody help me out with this please?

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with sails.js so I am not sure on how to apply the recommended method as described in your link. Nevertheless, I would like to propose a couple of other options:

First, you can isolate pieces of angular code within your nunjucks template inside raw tags (from [documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html)):

```
{% raw %}
  this will {{ not be processed }} (inside nunjucks)
{％ endraw %}
```

Although this looks like a great limitation, in fact I believe is very neat because it properly distinguishes where is which, and improves debugging a lot. If you need to pass options to angular controller you can do so in a script block outside of the raw blocks.

But when this is not always possible, you can change the angular tags ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider)). For instance:

```
var my_app = angular.module('MyApp').config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
});
```